# Deploy some files using pillars and jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I would like to deploy many files on my nginx proxy with Saltstack.
My proxy will host a configuration file in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/[WEBSERVER]` for every webserver that I have.

So in all my pillars files for every minion with the grain `role:webserver`, I put the following:

```
proxy:
  hostname: NAME OF THE WEBSERVER
  dns_suffixe: TEST1.FR
```

On my second minion, i've got the same with a different value and so on.

So in the formula I use that code to match the value of the pillar:

```
{% for proxy, args in salt['pillar.get']('proxy').iteritems() %}

/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{hostname}}:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://proxy-ext/files/default.jinja
    - target: /etc/nginx/sites-available/{{hostname}}
    - template: jinja
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 640
{% endfor %}
```

I manage the file `default.jinja` with the same var `{{hostname}}` and the `{{dns_suffixe}`.

But this is not working. I'm still a newbie with Salt, and I'm not sure that is the best way to do what I want.
Is it possible to get back all the pillars value that I wrote in the pillar files of my webservers? Even if the key:value is always the following?

```
proxy:
  hostname: NAME
```

I'm using Salt 2017. My `top.sls` files are well defined.
Every answer is welcome ! I'm completely stuck. Help :3

EDIT

I'll try to rephrase differently to be more clear. 
The goal of that manipulation is to automate the uploading of many websites.
So I have one minion with a nginx proxy.
When I run my proxy formula, I want that Salt analyse my minions and match the webserver grains.
On all my webserver, there is a formula/pillar to deploy the application and on that same pillar, I have `proxy.hostname:value` and `proxy.cert:value` as defined above. With a different value for all the webserver pillars.

So when I run my proxy formula, it matchs my minions, and I want to get back every value in `proxy.hostname:value` and the other one to deploy the good configuration file on my nginx proxy for all my webservers.

(my default.jinja is the template of a nginx configuration file to upload a website)

So is it possible to get back that values with a kind of jinja loop on all that pillars value? Like something I wrote above?
I'm not really sure of the method I tried to use.
Sorry for the misunderstanding, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You may want to rephrase on what you want to do and how would you like the files on the servers to be. Also I don't understand what is in default.jinja and where hostname comes from. If hostname is defined in default.jinja you want want to import https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#include-and-import

Comment: I'm gonna check that link and I already edited above to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the context parameter to `file.managed` and then you can access the variables within the template

```
{% for proxy, args in salt['pillar.get']('proxy').items() %}

/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{hostname}}:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://proxy-ext/files/default.jinja
    - target: /etc/nginx/sites-available/{{hostname}}
    - template: jinja
    - context:
        hostname: {{ args['hostname'] }}
        dns_suffix: {{ args['dns_suffixe'] }}
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 640
{% endfor %}
```

After that you can reference the hostname and dns_suffix in the template as if they were defined locally.